# How do I know if a query call came from the network or the cache in Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I run a `useQuery` or a `useLazyQuery` in Apollo GraphQL.  How do I determine if the data is being returned from a network call or the cache?

It seems the iOS version supports this (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/blob/63eacd1fc5ac711b25d39ac0164ce1df7d7426de/Sources/Apollo/GraphQLResult.swift#L14), but it seems regular old apollo client does not.

Comment: When you use `useQuery`, the data comes from the cache during almost *every* render. When results from the network arrive, that will result in only a single render. Is it really useful to separate that out? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can use a [fetch policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries#supported-fetch-policies) to get data only from the cache or only from the network, if you really need to distinguish them.